# $\int \sqrt{x^4+1}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I have tried to find $\int \sqrt{x^4+1} dx$ but can not find a way to get the answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to integrate by parts, but i can't really get an answer.

Comment: How did you apply Integration By Parts (also, I highly doubt that this integral is solvable using elementary functions, since [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) gives up and Mathematica gives [this](https://imgur.com/a/2iSXndb)).

Comment: So if one had to do the calculation in hand, how would it be done?

Comment: You'd have to figure out a way to rewrite the thing as an elliptic integral. That is easier said than done, though.

Answer (score 2):

With this antiderivative, you face elliptic integrals of the first kind.

If you are not aware of them, I prefer to just give the result
$$\int \sqrt{x^4+1}\,dx=\frac{1}{3} \left(x \sqrt{x^4+1}-(1+i) \sqrt{2} F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{(1+i) }{\sqrt{2}}x\right)\right|-1\right)\right)$$

Oherwise, use series expansions
$$\sqrt{x^4+1}=\frac 1{2\sqrt \pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{ \Gamma \left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n!} x^{4n}$$ and integrate term wise.

Answer (score 2):

By the reduction and transformation formulas mentioned in my [*Elliptic Integrals and Functions*](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Dounreay/-/blob/9f728cd4e4f28135628ede7601e42f233220d967/misc/elliptic-integrals-and-functions.pdf) monograph
$$\int_0^y\sqrt{x^4+1}\,dx=\int_0^y\frac{x^4+1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\,dx=\frac{y\sqrt{y^4+1}}3+\frac23\int_0^y\frac1{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\,dx$$
$$=\frac{y\sqrt{y^4+1}}3+\frac23F\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{y^2+1-\sqrt{y^4+1}},m=\frac12\right)=\frac{y\sqrt{y^4+1}+F(2\tan^{-1}y,1/2)}3$$
In hypergeometric terms the integral is
$$y{_2F_1}(-1/2,1/4;5/4;-y^4)$$

Comment: What is F in this equation

Comment: @Tom First-kind elliptic integral.

Comment: is it possible to simplify F to somethinge else.

Comment: @Tom No. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to go to an integral table or software.  Regardless, here's the answer:

$$\frac{1}{3} \left(x \sqrt{x^4+1}-2 \sqrt[4]{-1} F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt[4]{-1} x\right)\right|-1\right)\right) ,$$

where $F$ is an elliptic integral.